# C++ Libraries in ROS Noetic

Tags: c++, ros

So I am a beginner programmer and I have been tasked to take a python file in a big ROS project, compiled with catkin_make, and turn it into c++. I have a lot of time and I wanted to learn more about c++. I begun by just importing the libraries we use in python into C++, or at least what is possible in C++. I started with
`#include <ros/ros.h>`
However, VSCode puts the line red and says : "cannot open source file "ros/ros.h". I have a CmakeList in the same folder as the python file I'm trying to turn into cpp. I added roscpp in the find_package(). Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong, this also happens with libraries like opencv2.

Thanks

I have tried to check for roscpp on my computer (Linux Focal Fossa), but it should already be there with the default installation of ROS Noetic.